# Set font-weight back if another li is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

On another question I asked if I could set the font-weight to bold on a text element when that text is selected. This has been completed much to the avail of @Eric ! But currently, when you click a text, you can happily click another one and both of the text will be bold.

How can I prevent more than one text element from being bold?

Here is my code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XMzf/ or below:

**CSS**:

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#background {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.navigationPlaceholder {
    width:100px;
    height: 400px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
#navigation {
    background-color: #000000;
}
#navigationText ul {
    font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz";
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #b2b2b2;
    left: 25px;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.noSelect {
  -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit browsers */
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Max Kramer | iOS Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background" />
        <div id="navigation" class="navigationPlaceholder">
            <div id="navigationText">
                <ul>
                    <li>iOS</li>
                    <li>Blog</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var nav = document.getElementById('navigationText');

            var navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');

            for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
                navItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    this.style.fontWeight = '400';
                }, false);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net it?

Comment: At least in FF 6, nothing is happening when I click on the elements. Note that putting an element HTML document in the frames in jsfiddle is not right.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/6XMzf/1/.

Comment: You're also linking to a CSS file that doesn't exist (on jsfiddle). And you still have a complete HTML document in the top, left frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a selector engine handy like jQuery and really have to do this in plain Javascript, I would do it like this:

```
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (elem.className.indexOf(className) == -1) {
        elem.className += " " + className;
    }
}

function removeClass(elem, className) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*" + className), "");
}

var lastSelected = null;

function initNavClickHandler() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('navigationText');
    var navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
        navItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            addClass(this, "selected");
            if (lastSelected) {
                removeClass(lastSelected, "selected");
            }
            lastSelected = this;
        }, false);
    }
}

initNavClickHandler();
```

Then, add a CSS rule that controls the selected look:

```
.selected {font-weight: 800;}
```

This is a lot more flexible for styling because you can add as many CSS rules as you want to the .selected class to change/modify it without ever touching your code.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rrxaQ/

Comment: Thanks, before I accept this, could you tell me how I could work out if the selected text is "Blog"?!

Comment: The best way to detect the blog LI is to put `class="blog"` on that LI tag.   You can also use different CSS based on that class.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w4Udw/ for a working example of HTML/CSS/JS.  You could use code to test the text of the tag, but that's not as desirable as using classes.

Comment: Its picking up every li tag for me, and running the if statement on all of those tags too, http://maxk.me/test/

Comment: Had has one paren in the wrong place in the `hasClass()` function. It is fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w4Udw/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use things like jQuery then this is a much simpler problem. Let me show you the jQuery solution for both highlighting and unhighlighting.

```
$("#navigationText li").click( function() { 
  $("#navigationText li").css("fontWeight", "100");
  $(this).css("fontWeight", "400");
});
```

Now you can achieve the same thing yourself without jQuery. You either need to create a global that holds the currently bolded item and remove the fontWeight or just remove the fontWeight from all items (brute force).

```
        //untested with global to store currently selected
        var nav = document.getElementById('navigationText');
        var activeItem = null;

        var navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
            navItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (activeItem) {activeItem.style.fontWeight = '100'; }
                this.style.fontWeight = '400';
                activeItem = this;
            }, false);
        }

        //sorry I don't feel like writing a brute force one for you!
```

Comment: Ok, I am pretty new to html+css and I have never used jquery, where would I put the jquery code?